# Test if semantic triple occurs more often than by chance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, text-mining

I have a large table (more than 9,000,000 rows) of semantic predications (i.e., triples of subject-predicate-object) extracted from sentences of scientific abstracts. The data are organized in the following form:

```
Subject Predicate Object Frequency
----------------------------------
A       TREATS    B      12 
A       TREATS    C       3
B       CAUSES    C      10
B       TREATS    D       1
D       PREVENTS  E       5
etc.
----------------------------------
```

Subjects and concepts are typically biomedical concepts (e.g., Aspirin, Dementia) but for simplicity, I use letters in the table above.

**Question:** I would like to test if a particular predication occurs more often than by chance. I would be grateful for any suggestions or ideas.

I think that my problem is similar to finding significant collocations, as explained in [Manning and Schütze](https://nlp.stanford.edu/fsnlp/promo/colloc.pdf) (p. 160); however, in the case of collocations, we only have two variables (e.g., Subject and Object) and frequency of their co-occurrence, a problem that is solved by applying chi-square test of independence.